# Java HashMap/ArrayList object keeps asking for initialCapacity/LoadFactor instead of the requested K/V pair

Tags: java, hashmap, load-factor

I´m unable to create HashMap/ArrayList objects. If I try to create a new HashMap, IntelliJ is asking for initialCapacity and LoadFactor, which is supposed to be an int/float. If I declare a HashMap with String/String K/V the code is underlined, IntelliJ can recognise it as a new object, but the put method is missing or not recognised. I´m not sure what could cause it, I have reinstalled the JDK and IntelliJ but the problem remains. I have also opened some older rojects where anything written previously works fine, however new lines produce the same issue.
Here is snippet of my code just as an example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {
    HashMap<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>("firstString", "secondString");
    testMap.put("first", "second");
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p8Fg.png)

Some data that might be relevant:
-java version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
-IntelliJ community IDEA 2022.2.3

Thanks a lot for the help in advance, and sorry for the bad formatting, I´ll make sure to improve it in the future.

Comment: Look at [the list of HashMap constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#constructor-summary).  See the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor of `HashMap` that receives a sequence of keys and values.

Either use:

```
HashMap<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("firstString", "secondString");
testMap.put("first", "second");
```

or

```
Map<String,String> testMap = Map.of("firstString", "secondString", "first", "second");
```

(although the latter is immutable)

Comment: Definietly eye opening, I should read documentations as everybody suggests it. Actually I ended up with this syntax after experimenting, as creating an empty HashMap didn’t work out. The issue is still there, it’s not the source of the problem.

Comment: Just an update on it because someone might make the same mistake. The HashMap/ArrayList can be declared as a variable but adding elements is only possible in a constructor of the class or in a method.